# Why can't I open the info window again when I use google api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I just want to add the google API to have a little map in a website, but I noticed, that the info window opens and then if I close it i cant open it again, I need to refresh the page.

Any idea how can a fix this little bug? Here is my code.

```
function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(42.42895, 19.27435), 14);
        map.setUIToDefault();


        var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(42.42895, 19.27435), {  
        draggable: false,  
        title: 'Kuca nemanja'  
        });             

        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {  
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml('<b>Ovde zivi moj drug <a href="#">link</a></b>');  
        map.closeInfoWindow(); 
        });                         

        map.addOverlay(marker);

      }
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is map.closeInfoWindow(); but im not sure. Can you remove it from your initial call and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for everyone to know, the map.closeInfoWindow(); caused the infowindow to close before the close button was clicked therefore when try opening the infowindow again the item could not be opened it was 'double closed'.

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {  
 marker.openInfoWindowHtml('<b>Ovde zivi moj drug <a href="#">link</a></b>');  
});
```